# What is another word for amount that doesn't mean a portion or dose?

Tags: word-choice

The word amount means a "*quantity of something, typically the total of a thing or things in number, size, value, or extent.*" - Google.

It gives the feeling of a contained amount of something.

I need a word that doesn't give the meaning of contained amount, but it should mean an uncertain amount that'll only keep rising.

For example a daily "*dose*" means a daily fixed amount.

I need is to say, "*your daily _ of technology*" so dose doesn't fit there and amount doesn't either.

**EDIT:** It should mean something like: *Receive your exceptional, daily _ of technology.*
In the context of a subscription form.

Comment: How 'bout exposure?

Comment: Nope... That doesn't fit very well in the context.

Comment: Could you explain why *dose* doesn't fit?

Comment: The word dose generally is used in the context of medicine. Also, it means a set amount.
**Edit** Google's words: _a quantity of a medicine or drug taken or recommended to be taken at a particular time._

Comment: I think that's where you may be under a misunderstanding.  While *dose* does come from the medical world, it's very natural to use it metaphorically in other contexts.  "*Your daily dose of technology*" sounds quite natural to my ear.  And while a dose may mean a set amount there's nothing that says it's fixed forever.  Doses change up and down all the time.  One could easily see increasing their dose of technology as time goes on.

Comment: @Jim's right. *Your daily dose of _____*, where _____ is anything at all, is fine.  (And a daily dose need not be a constant amount. I need my daily dose of world news, but the amount varies according to how I feel.)

Comment: A dose is a needed amount, nothing more.  How much is needed can change.

Comment: @Drew Exactly, a dose is a needed amount. In other words it's what somebody would require. My sentence would go as "Receive your rare daily dose of technology." - So dose doesn't really fit there.. For example, it's an exceptional piece that is sent to a user on a daily basis. And it's for a subscription form.

Comment: I cannot comment on whether it is something that someone would consider they need daily.  The only thing that seems a bit out of place in your sentence is "*rare*".  That doesn't fit with the notion of something someone does daily, habitually or regularly.

Comment: Okay... Exceptional instead of rare. An "exceptional piece".

Comment: @ermanen um, how should I use that in the context of a subscription form that's inviting the user to subscribe to a blog? I mean, like I said before, it needs to mean an exceptional piece that you'd receive daily..

Comment: @Jim maybe I should go with the word dose for now... Add it as an answer. If someone else posts something better I'll change it later onwards.

Comment: How about "Your daily window on technology"?

Comment: Might I suggest rephrasing? From what I understand, you are offering one article on technology per day, and want to express that this article (or, perhaps, the technology) is 'exceptional'. Perhaps try "Receive an exceptional article on technology every day" or "Receive your daily report on exceptional technology."

Comment: Yeah absolutely, if a total rephrase can help get the same effect and message across, that'd be great. I thought up the phrase "_Coffee and your Morning's Read..._" but that has nothing in common with technology : (.

Answer (score 2):

- Your daily fix of ganja/technology/English-lessons.
- Your daily infusion of ganja/technology/knowledge.
- Your daily nourishment of technology/knowledge.
- Your daily abuse of ganja/knowledge.
- Your daily fest of ganja/technology/knowledge.
- Your daily repast of ganja/technology/knowledge.
- Your daily indulgence of ganja/technology/knowledge.
- Your daily binge of ganja/technology/knowledge.
- Your daily orgy of ganja/technology/knowledge.
- Your daily gratification of ganja/technology/knowledge.

Comment: "Fix" is the best fit for this context.

Answer (score 0):

"your daily **[apportionment](http://law.academic.ru/4242/apportionment)** of technology"

> noun administration, allocation, allotment, allowance, assignment,
>   assignment in proportion, consignment, disposition, distribution,
>   division, division in proportion, doling out, issuance, just division,
>   measuring out, meting out, partition, partitionment, proportionment

Comment: I would assume the subscription to be either about legal stuff - or, since technology is mentioned, it gets an Indian ring to my ears. That is not necessarily bad, but something to be considered... (InE has a tendency to use words and expressions that can appear dated or even antiquated to speakers of other dialects - I personally have a weakness for it, but in a technology environment it may not be the intended effect.)

Answer (score 0):

Try *quota,* which conveys the notion of a minimum portion size. It also starts with the letter Q, which automatically raises its coolness quotient.

Comment: It also has legal connotations, which immediately drop it quoolness quotient by many more quanta than the _Q_ alone could raise it...

Comment: @oerkelens - Qdos on your extensive use of the letter Q in your comment! However, I don't think the OP's context invites a particularly legalistic interpretation; the OP is offering a subscription to a technology-related product of some kind (since it's daily, I'm guessing it's an emailed newsletter), not following an HR hiring policy.

Comment: I was not referring to the questioner's context, but to your _quota_ - it gives me the idea of an amount that is measured (and _limited_!) by the powers that be. And I don't think the OP wants to say: get this subscription, and you will get a rationed amount of technology. Subscribe now and I will make sure you get no more technology than what I deem enough for you!

Answer (score 0):

**quantum** is always a good one
(especially if we go by the coolness factor mentioned with quota :))

portion or allotment could be another useful word but usual indicates a part of a whole more than an undefined amount. But for the example of *your daily __ of technology* it would be usable.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I doubt many people would construe the use of *dose* or *portion* to mean the quantity will be fixed.

Your daily *dispatch*
Your daily *delivery*

... of Technological Tidings?

On the food metaphor front:

Your daily *serve*
Your daily *serving*
Your daily *helping*
Your daily *scoop*
Your daily *dollop*

... of Technological Tidbits?